# Linux version of Eclipse - logcat not showing Android project logs

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, logcat

I have read many of the posts for logcat not displaying in Eclipse and so far nothing has solved my problem. I have two installs. Logcat in Eclipse installed on my windows laptop works, but on my Linux Mint laptop those same programs will not display in logcat and not just with my log command in the program, but nothing shows - not even a trace.

The command line options of using adb logcat shows the logs just fine. It just won't show in the logcat window in Eclipse.

I have made sure the emulator is selected on the device tab, I have reset adb, I have restarted eclipse,Under  I made sure "Monitor logcat for messages from applications in workspace" was checked and selected "VERBOSE".

I don't have any filters set.

Any ideas on what to try next?

I have had other problems with this linux installation that I had to fix. For instance, the default Google Eclipse/Plugin Bundle had some bugs. Some of which were solved with a new version of Eclipse and some were solved with a new version of ADT.The version of ADT also had a bug that would not let you upgrade it through Eclipse. So, I removed that bundle install and re-installed everything manually:Eclipse 4.4, then installed the 4.4 plugin and the various build tools and API levels and extras I needed. That solved some of those bugs.

That left the logcat issue and one major bug. Eclipse would freeze-up when the android auto-complete pop-up would display. On a hunch, I decided to run Android-Studio to see if it had any freeze-ups. When I started Studio, it warned me that I was using OpenJDK and it has known GUI performance problems and hangs. It gave a message that it recommended that I install the offical Oracle JDK, which I then did. That solved freeze-ups and hangs on Eclipse with the Android auto complete popups.

Now just this one problem left to solve - on my Linux environment, making logcat within Eclipse wok. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I also faced different kinds of problem in some last ADT Bundles(eclipse) in ubuntu.I think google is not giving too much attention in this. My suggestion is to use Android studio & this is also encouraged by google to use it.

Comment: Sayem, After my experience with getting this working on Linux, I have thought exploring the idea of moving to studio. I have not used it has of yet, so I would need to both see if I like it and see how easy it is to migrate all my projects in Eclipse over to it,before I could decide to make such move. Has your experience with Android Studio been good?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I am also recently using Android Studio & I felt that it's user experience is better than eclipse. There is process of migrating projects from eclipse to android studio given in developer.android. U can try a demo, then migrate your actual project. Link : https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html